# Domain coloring (color wheel) plots of complex functions in Octave (Matlab)

Tags: plot, octave, complex-numbers, colormap

I understand that [domain or color wheel plotting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring) is typical for complex functions.

Incredibly, I can't find a million + returns on a web search to easily allow me to reproduce some piece of art as this one in Wikipedia:

[image]

There is this [online resource](http://davidbau.com/conformal/#z%5E2) that reproduces plots with zeros in black - not bad at all... However, I'd like to ask for some simple annotated code in Octave to produce color plots of functions of complex numbers.

Here is an example:

[image: domain plotting of complex functions]

I see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/visualizing-four-dimensional-data.html?requestedDomain=true) code to plot a complex function. However, it uses a different technique with the height representing the Re part of the image of the function, and the color representing the imaginary part:

[image: Example of Matlab solution to visualize 4D data]

Comment: Are you talking about 2D functions?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm looking at complex functions of complex variables: R^2 maps to R^2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Peter Kovesi](http://peterkovesi.com/projects/colourmaps/index.html) has some fantastic color maps. He provides a [MATLAB function, called `colorcet`](http://www.peterkovesi.com/matlabfns/Colourmaps/colorcet.m), that we can use here to get the cyclic color map we need to represent the phase. *Download this function before running the code below.*

Let's start with creating a complex-valued test function `f`, where the magnitude increases from the center, and the phase is equal to the angle around the center. Much like the example you show:

```
% A test function
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(-128:128,-128:128);
z = xx + yy*1i;
f = z;
```

Next, we'll get its phase, convert it into an index into the `colorcet` C2 color map (which is cyclic), and finally reshape that back into the original function's shape. `out` here has 3 dimensions, the first two are the original dimensions, and the last one is RGB. `imshow` shows such a 3D matrix as a color image.

```
% Create a color image according to phase
cm = colorcet('C2');
phase = floor((angle(f) + pi) * ((size(cm,1)-1e-6) / (2*pi))) + 1;
out = cm(phase,:);
out = reshape(out,[size(f),3]);
```

The last part is to modulate the intensity of these colors using the magnitude of `f`. To make the discontinuities at powers of two, we take the base 2 logarithm, apply the modulo operation, and compute the power of two again. A simple multiplication with `out` decreases the intensity of the color where necessary:

```
% Compute the intensity, with discontinuities for |f|=2^n
magnitude = 0.5 * 2.^mod(log2(abs(f)),1);
out = out .* magnitude;
```

That last multiplication works in Octave and in the later versions of MATLAB. For older versions of MATLAB you need to use `bsxfun` instead:

```
out = bsxfun(@times,out,magnitude);
```

Finally, display using `imshow`:

```
% Display
imshow(out)
```

[image: output of code above]

Note that the colors here are more muted than in your example. The `colorcet` color maps are perceptually uniform. That means that the same change in angle leads to the same perceptual change in color. In the example you posted, for example yellow is a very narrow, bright band. Such a band leads to false highlighting of certain features in the function, which might not be relevant at all. Perceptually uniform color maps are very important for proper interpretation of the data. Note also that this particular color map has easily-named colors (purple, blue, green, yellow) in the four cardinal directions. A purely real value is green (positive) or purple (negative), and a purely imaginary value is blue (positive) or yellow (negative).

Comment: Very nice. Thank you! I can't upvote due to low rep. I'll come back to it later...

Comment: Your answer is great. I am having some problems reproducing with Octave. Specifically, I get an `error: 'colorcet' undefined near line 5 column 6`. I don't use Octave/Matlab often at all, and I did ask for it specifically because I don't have access to Mathematica, and I figured that Matlab would be big on complex plotting options. However, my degree of comfort importing packages and such is minimal. I was also waiting for other alternative answers. My intention was to upvote. And I will close the post eventually.

Comment: @shouldn'tbehere: you need to download `colorcet` from the link I proved at the top of the answer. Sorry for not making that explicit.

Comment: I had actually arrived at that page trying to replicate your findings. I do see that the URL address ends in `.m`, a big hint that it is a matlab file. But I don't know what to do with it. Do you select everything in the page, copy and past on the Octave console, or do you right-click (Windows) and save somewhere among the Octave folders? If so, do you happen to know where?

Comment: @shouldn'tbehere: Right-click on the link and save to your current directory. Octave will find it there. If you need to be able to access it from multiple directories, save it to any directory of your choosing and add that directory to the Octave path using `addpath` (note that the path is not saved from session to session, so you'll need to do that every time you launch Octave). The file `~/.octaverc` (on Linux and MacOS) is executed every time you start Octave, you can put the `addpath` command in there too.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to reproduce it. Rest assured that I will definitely come back to accept, and upvote your post once I have enough reputation. Although the probability of having alternative answers is slim, I'd like to keep it open for a little bit longer just in case.

Comment: Actually, if you can clarify how to change the function f, I'll just go ahead and accept your answer, thanking you for all your help.

Comment: I have made the post explicit that I plot `f = z`. If you want to plot a different function, simply compute it from the `z`: For example, `f = (z/30).^3 - 4` looks very pretty. Note the `z/30`, this is to make the plot sampled more densely, it doesn't look good if it is sampled too sparsely. You can also try plotting `f = exp(z/30)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your help was awesome, and regardless of what happens to this post in the future, your answer is *the* answer. I'm a bit more disappointed with Matlab - I was hoping for plots like the one in the edited OP. BTW When I get more rep, I'll come back and +1 your post for all the added help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is also a great [online tool made by Juan Carlos Ponce Campuzano](https://www.dynamicmath.xyz/complex/function-plotter/hsv.htm) for color wheel plotting.

In my experience it is much easier to use than the Octave solution. The downside is that you cannot use perceptually uniform coloring.