# Quantizing an image in matlab

Tags: matlab

So I'm trying to figure out why my code doesn't seem to be displaying the properly uniformed quantized image into 4 levels.

```
Q1 =uint8(zeros(ROWS, COLS, CHANNELS));
for band = 1 : CHANNELS,
    for x = 1 : ROWS,
        for y = 1 : COLS,

Q1(ROWS,COLS,CHANNELS) = uint8(double(I1(ROWS,COLS,CHANNELS) / 2^4)*2^4);
        end    
    end
end
No5 = figure;
imshow(Q1);
title('Part D: K = 4');
```

Comment: Dividing by 16 won't give you 4 levels unless your original image had only 64 levels. Is that the case?

Comment: The original image has 256 gray levels.

Comment: Your image can't have 256 gray levels if it's possibly a multi-channel image (i.e. `CHANNELS`).  Please confirm if you have a grayscale or colour image.  If it's colour, please specify the desired quantization per channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are not quantifying. You divide a double by 16, then multiply again by 16, then convert it to uint8. The right way to quantize is to divide by 16, throw away any decimals, then multiply by 16:

```
Q1 = uint8(floor(I1 / 16) * 16);
```

In the code snippet above, I assume `I1` is a `double`. Convert it to `double` if its not: `I1=double(I1)`.

Note that you don't need the loops, MATLAB will apply the operation to each element in the matrix.

Note also that if `I1` is an integer type, you can do something like this:

```
Q1 = (uint8(I1) / 16) * 16;
```

but this is actually equivalent to replacing the `floor` by `round` in the first example. This means you get an uneven distribution of values: 0-7 are mapped to 0, 8-23 are mapped to 16, etc. and 248-255 are all mapped to 255 (not a multiple of 16!). That is, 8 numbers are mapped to 0, and 8 are mapped to 255, instead of mapping 16 numbers to each possible multiple of 16 as the `floor` code does.

The `16` in the code above means that there will be `256/16=16` different grey levels in the output. If you want a different number, say `n`, use `256/n` instead of `16`.

Comment: Ahh I see. So there's no need to create for loops. But this would do the quantizing as I've discussed right? I'm also looking into doing this through natural logarithm quantization, how would one do it?

Comment: That's a new question. But yesterday I answered a related question, where I show how to apply a logarithmic modulus. You can easily modify that answer to apply a logarithmic floor function. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48981934/7328782

Comment: Apologies on that, I'll test the code tonight and see if it follows the imquantize function. While you;re here, I'm curious of the difference between using the floor function and without it.

Comment: @MarorinQ: The two alternatives are not identical, I forgot that MATLAB does strange integer division. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Does this divide the 256 levels into 4 though?

Comment: @MarorinQ: Sorry, I posted that I had updated the answer before actually updating it. It now is. I think this answers your latest question too: The `floor` variant maps all 256 levels evenly onto the multiples of 16.

Comment: I am not sure whether that's what I need as if like to uniformly quantized into 4 grayscale levels.

Comment: @MarorinQ: I used 16 here because you used `2^4`, which is 16. If you want to divide evenly into 4 greyscale levels, use `256/4=64` instead: `uint8(floor(I1 / 64) * 64)`

Comment: Ahhhh alright then. Now I get it. Are there equivalent ways that would replicate the floor function or is that the standard way to do it without the imquantize function.

Comment: @MarorinQ: `floor` is the correct way to do it. If you only deal with positive data, this is equivalent to `fix`. I don't know if `fix` is faster than `floor`. `floor` rounds towards minus infinity, `fix` rounds towards 0. You can see that these are identical for positive values, but opposite for negative ones. The common alternative, casting to `uint8` (as in the other answer), rounds towards the nearest integer (`round`), which is not what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks. I was just curious as the wiki article for signal quantization also has a floor function and a delta as well as other additions so just felt the need to ask in those cases. Ill look and apply this tonight so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using `ROWS, COLS, CHANNELS` as your index, it should be `x,y,band`. Also, the final multiplication of 2^4 has be after the uint8 cast otherwise no rounding ever takes place.

In practice you should avoid the for loops in Matlab since matrix operations are much faster. Replace your code with

```
Q1=uint8(double(I1/2^4))*2^4
No5 = figure;
imshow(Q1);
title('Part D: K = 4');
```

Comment: I hadn't even noticed the wrong indexing. Good catch!